# PHP: Locale aware number format

Tags: php, internationalization

I want to format the number 3253454 for my website visitors.

If I use the inbuilt number_format function, I get: 3,253,454 which is great for UK and USA, however most other countries use 3.253.454

I have many international visitors.

Can anyone give me a pointer to the best practice here?

Ideally I wish to get the browser's locale and format the number accordingly. Is this even possible in PHP?

Answer (score 24):

If you're deploying a localized website, you're going to want to make sure you [setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale).  To riff off of yaauie's above post I'd add something like the following code snippet in your initialization code:

```
$locale = ( isset($_COOKIE['locale']) ) ? 
            $_COOKIE['locale'] : 
            $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
```

Then we modify the above function `number_format_locale()`, to look like so:

```
function number_format_locale($number,$decimals=2) {
    $locale = localeconv();
    return number_format($number,$decimals,
               $locale['decimal_point'],
               $locale['thousands_sep']);
 }
```

Of course that's in an ideal world, depending on the platform you deploy to, and what version of the locale files you have installed, you might have to code around some irregularities.  But setting locale is going to help with money, numbers, and dates.

Comment: Genius. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Beware that setlocale() isn't thread-safe.  That means if you're running PHP on a server that uses threads instead of processes (or plan to someday), don't use setlocale() to change the locale.  See the new answer suggesting NumberFormatter, which is now the preferred way to do this.

Comment: When there's a `"thousands_sep" => b" "` (e.g. _sk_SK_ locale), it doesn't work. In blade, `{{ number_format_locale(2500) }}` shows nothing.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe try approach independent from setting global locale for all scripts?

**Get user's locale:**

```
$locale = ( isset($_COOKIE['locale']) ) ? 
            $_COOKIE['locale'] : 
            $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
```

**Format the number:**

I recommend using [PHP NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php). It's an OOP approach which uses [ICU library](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php).

```
$formatStyle=NumberFormatter::DECIMAL;
$formatter= new NumberFormatter($locale, $formatStyle);
echo $formatter->format(3253454);//proper output depending on locale
```

You can use many different style formats there, for example: DECIMAL, CURRENCY or PERCENT. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants.unumberformatstyle).

It's best way of number formatting, because it depends on global [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://codel10n.com/what-is-cldr/).

Answer (score 9):

```
string number_format (float $number, int $decimals, string $dec_point, string $thousands_sep)
```

see [php doku for number_format](https://www.php.net/number_format)

Another helpful link may be [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) from Zend Framework - it can detect your user's language and also help with number/currency formatting

Answer (score 5):

PHP meanwhile offers a NumberFormatter Class which is perfect for this purpose:

http://php.net/manual/de/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Except that you now need to type 3 lines of code instead of a single number_format() statement.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#76448:

```
<?php

    function strtonumber( $str, $dec_point=null, $thousands_sep=null )
    {
        if( is_null($dec_point) || is_null($thousands_sep) ) {
            $locale = localeconv();
            if( is_null($dec_point) ) {
                $dec_point = $locale['decimal_point'];
            }
            if( is_null($thousands_sep) ) {
                $thousands_sep = $locale['thousands_sep'];
            }
        }
        $number = (float) str_replace($dec_point, '.', str_replace($thousands_sep, '', $str));
        if( $number == (int) $number ) {
            return (int) $number;
        } else {
            return $number;
        }
    }

?>
```

That seems to be exactly what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use Zend Framework. In this case I use such thing:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('fr_FR');
$number = Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber(2.5, array('locale' => $locale));

// will return 2,5
print $number;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE server variable to guess their locale and expected number format.

If I were to implement this, I'd allow a user to set a preference to override the guessed, and my function would look like this:

```
function number_format_locale($number,$decimals=2) {
    $locale = ( isset($_COOKIE['locale']) ? 
                    $_COOKIE['locale'] : 
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
               )
    switch($locale) {
        case 'en-us':
        case 'en-ca':
            $decimal = '.';
            $thousands = ',';
            break;
        case 'fr':
        case 'ca':
        case 'de':
        case 'en-gb':
            $decimal = ',';
            $thousands = ' ';
            break;
        case 'es':
        case 'es-mx':
        default:
            $decimal = ',';
            $thousands = ' ';
    }
    return $number_format($number,$decimals,$decimal,$thousands);
}
```

Comment: Please note that I do not know (nor have researched) the expected formats of the above locales.

Comment: we use $decimal = '.' and $thousands = ',' here in 'sunny' blighty (en-gb) :)