# How to change 1,300.00 to 1300,00

Tags: php, numbers

In my PHP outputs, number shows 1,234.56

How can I change this to 1234,56 or 1.234,56?

What is the American way and European way?

Does php work with American way?

Comment: In most of Europe, anyway. The British agree with the Americans in this regard.

Comment: There's no European way, different locales use different standards (I do believe the UK uses the same 1,234.56 as well?) Most countries in Europe will use ',' as a decimal separator though. The period for thousands though, not so sure about that one. At least some use a space for it (1 234,56).. You'll need some kind of localization routines to get it right for a particular locale. The number_format answer answers your question though, right?

Comment: You may also be interested in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371) if you may need to support more locales some day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [number_format](http://www.php.net/number_format):

```
echo number_format($num, 2, ',', '.');
```

With the arguments being:

1. The number itself
2. Amount of decimal points
3. Separator of decimal points
4. Separator of thousands

The european way varies regionally and can be one of these:

- `123.456,50` (eg. German)
- `123,456.50` (eg. English)
- `123 456,50` (eg. French)
- `123'456,50` (eg. Swiss)

The american way is `123,456.50` and yes, all formats work. It doesn't matter how you output them, PHP handles floats internally in `123456.50` format.

Comment: The variable is a string 1,072.00 and if I use number_format it outputs 1,00.
If the number is 1070.00, it works. But 1,070.00 does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the format details for the current locale using localeconv (http://php.net/localeconv):

```
<?php
if (false !== setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL.UTF-8@euro')) {
    $locale_info = localeconv();
    print_r($locale_info);
}
?>
```

Which will give something like:

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] =>
    [int_curr_symbol] => EUR
    [currency_symbol] => €
    [mon_decimal_point] => ,
    [mon_thousands_sep] =>
    [positive_sign] =>
    [negative_sign] => -
    [int_frac_digits] => 2
    [frac_digits] => 2
    [p_cs_precedes] => 1
    [p_sep_by_space] => 1
    [n_cs_precedes] => 1
    [n_sep_by_space] => 1
    [p_sign_posn] => 1
    [n_sign_posn] => 2
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Why use Zend_Currency?

Zend_Currency offers the following functions for handling currency manipulations:

```
* Complete Locale support: Zend_Currency works with all available locales and therefore knows about over 100 different localized currencies. This includes currency names, abbreviations, money signs and more.
* Reusable Currency Definitions: Zend_Currency does not include the value of the currency. This is the reason why its functionality is not included in Zend_Locale_Format. Zend_Currency has the advantage that already defined currency representations can be reused.

* Fluent Interface: Zend_Currency includes fluent interfaces where possible.

* Additional Methods: Zend_Currency includes additional methods that offer information about which regions a currency is used in or which currency is used in a specified region.
```

```
// creates an instance with 'en_US' using 'USD', which is the default
// values for 'en_US'
$currency = new Zend_Currency('en_US');

// prints '$ 1,000.00'
echo $currency->toCurrency(1000);
```

It is not exactly what you asked for, you just have to find a proper locale.