# customize format number to flexible

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have php code as following:

```
<?php
class number_word {
    private $word_array = array(1=>"One",2=>"Two",3=>"Three",4=>"Four",5=>"Five",6=>"Six",7=>"Seven",8=>"Eight",9=>"Nine",10=>"Ten",11=>"Eleven",12=>"Twelve",13=>"Thirteen",14=>"Fourteen",15=>"Fifteen",16=>"Sixteen",17=>"Seventeen",18=>"Eighteen",19=>"Nineteen",20=>"Twenty",21=>"Twenty-One",22=>"Twenty-Two",23=>"Twenty-Three",24=>"Twenty-Four",25=>"Twenty-Five",26=>"Twenty-Six",27=>"Twenty-Seven",28=>"Twenty-Eight",29=>"Twenty-Nine",30=>"Thirty",31=>"Thirty-One",32=>"Thirty-Two",33=>"Thirty-Three",34=>"Thirty-Four",35=>"Thirty-Five",36=>"Thirty-Six",37=>"Thirty-Seven",38=>"Thirty-Eight",39=>"Thirty-Nine",40=>"Forty",41=>"Forty-One",42=>"Forty-Two",43=>"Forty-Three",44=>"Forty-Four",45=>"Forty-Five",46=>"Forty-Six",47=>"Forty-Seven",48=>"Forty-Eight",49=>"Forty-Nine",50=>"Fifty",51=>"Fifty-One",52=>"Fifty-Two",53=>"Fifty-Three",54=>"Fifty-Four",55=>"Fifty-Five",56=>"Fifty-Six",57=>"Fifty-Seven",58=>"Fifty-Eight",59=>"Fifty-Nine",60=>"Sixty",61=>"Sixty-One",62=>"Sixty-Two",63=>"Sixty-Three",64=>"Sixty-Four",65=>"Sixty-Five",66=>"Sixty-Six",67=>"Sixty-Seven",68=>"Sixty-Eight",69=>"Sixty-Nine",70=>"Seventy",71=>"Seventy-One",72=>"Seventy-Two",73=>"Seventy-Three",74=>"Seventy-Four",75=>"Seventy-Five",76=>"Seventy-Six",77=>"Seventy-Seven",78=>"Seventy-Eight",79=>"Seventy-Nine",80=>"Eighty",81=>"Eighty-One",82=>"Eighty-Two",83=>"Eighty-Three",84=>"Eighty-Four",85=>"Eighty-Five",86=>"Eighty-Six",87=>"Eighty-Seven",88=>"Eighty-Eight",89=>"Eighty-Nine",90=>"Ninety",91=>"Ninety-One",92=>"Ninety-Two",93=>"Ninety-Three",94=>"Ninety-Four",95=>"Ninety-Five",96=>"Ninety-Six",97=>"Ninety-Seven",98=>"Ninety-Eight",99=>"Ninety-Nine",100=>"One Hundred",200=>"Two Hundred",300=>"Three Hundred",400=>"Four Hundred",500=>"Five Hundred",600=>"Six Hundred",700=>"Seven Hundred",800=>"Eight Hundred",900=>"Nine Hundred");

    private $thousand = array("", "Thousand, ", "Million, ", "Billion, ", "Trillion, ", "Zillion, ");

    private $val, $currency0, $currency1;   
    private $val_array, $dec_value, $dec_word, $num_value, $num_word;
    var $val_word;

    public function number_word($in_val = 0, $in_currency0 = "", $in_currency1 = "") {

        $this->val = $in_val;
        $this->currency0 = $in_currency0;
        $this->currency1 = $in_currency1;

        $this->val = abs(floatval(str_replace(",","",$this->val)));

        if ($this->val > 0) {

            $this->val = number_format($this->val, '2', ',', ',');

            $this->val_array = explode(",", $this->val);

            $this->dec_value = intval($this->val_array[count($this->val_array) - 1]);

            if ($this->dec_value > 0) {

                $this->dec_word = $this->word_array[$this->dec_value]." ".$this->currency1;
            }

            $t = 0;

            $this->num_word = "";

            for ($i = count($this->val_array) - 2; $i >= 0; $i--) {

                $this->num_value = intval($this->val_array[$i]);

                if ($this->num_value == 0) {
                    $this->num_word = "".$this->num_word;
                } 

                elseif (strlen($this->num_value."") <= 2) {
                    $this->num_word = $this->word_array[$this->num_value]." ".$this->thousand[$t].$this->num_word;
                    // add 'and' if not last element in VAL
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        $this->num_word = " and ".$this->num_word;
                    }               
                } 
                else {
                    $this->num_word = $this->word_array[substr($this->num_value, 0, 1)."00"]. (intval(substr($this->num_value, 1, 2)) > 0 ? " and " : "") .$this->word_array[intval(substr($this->num_value, 1, 2))]." ".$this->thousand[$t].$this->num_word;
                }
                $t++;
            }       
            if (!empty($this->num_word)) {
                $this->num_word .= " ".$this->currency0;
            }
        }
        $this->val_word = $this->num_word." ".$this->dec_word;
    }
}
?>
```

code above can be properly read format number 7,052,853.62 but I also want the code able to read other types of formatting numbers, for example; 7.052.853,62 or 7 052 853,62 and when I change comma into dot at line e.g.

```
    $this->val = abs(floatval(str_replace(",","",$this->val)));
    if ($this->val > 0) {
                    $this->val = number_format($this->val, '2', ',', ',');

                    $this->val_array = explode(",", $this->val);
```

UPDATE:
testing:

> echo $nw->number_word('52,853.62',
>   'Dollar', 'Cent');

then the code can no longer read the cent format number, what i should do to fix it? any pointers I would appreciate and thanks

Comment: what you have a problem with my friend is 'locales'.  the interchanging of the dot and the comma as the thousands and the decimal separator is for German locale.  I will read more on this and try to post an answer.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format. and search stackoverflow and google for php locale

Comment: hi kinjal, yes i have read that link, thanks, but regarding to the code above how to be able to read format number by figured the separator from to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace any character other than a digit with a blank in the first assignment made to $this->val.
i.e.

```
    public function number_word($in_val = 0, $in_currency0 = "", $in_currency1 = "") {    
        //$this->val = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $in_val);
        $this->val = str_replace(",", ".", preg_replace('/(\d+)\./', '$1', $in_val)); 
.
.
.
.
.
```

Edit: 1)Remove g flag from Regex
2) Added the str_replace and changed the regex to handle German and US/UK format

Comment: I appreciate your help and thanks, that your code 2 lines only and then blanks? OK after using it i got Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Hi Cybermate, Now I have the result, when I put 52,853.62 then code read as Five Million, Two Hundred and Eighty-Five Thousand, Three Hundred and Sixty-Two Dollar, it mean can't read cent and also fail to read number format. and if I put 52.853,62 then read is Five Million, Two Hundred and Eighty-Five Thousand, Three Hundred and Sixty-Two Dollar, it missing cent and number format, and if only I change at the code from comma to dot that also have same problem, thanks You.

Comment: Can you confirm if you will consider the , or . before last two characters as a decimal seperator?

Comment: by default the code is read UK / US format number with (.) as decimal separator, but then I'm ask for the code can be read Germany format number (,) as decimal separator e.g. echo $nw->number_word('52,853.62', 'Dollar', 'Cent'); as default (UK/US) and also able to read echo $nw->number_word('52.853,62', 'Mark', 'Cent'); as (Germany) format number. anyway thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yes, i checked it and work, You great, Thanks for your awesome code, and I only need to make conditional, so if I want to use UK/US format then i figured with $this->val = $in_val; if I want use Germany format then use your code above, else it also able to use Francaise format with replace your code from dot to space (francaise format e.g. 52 853.62 or 52 853,62), right? many thanks

Comment: You need not make a conditional parse as the code handles both US/UK and German. For France your assumption is correct

Comment: HI, for France number format is 52 853,62 that (,) as decimal separator and Your code only read the decimal value, but work fine if (.) as decimal separator, what I should do? and sorry but do you have another idea to fix it to swiss format? e.g. echo $nw->number_word('52'853,62', 'franc', 'Cent'); that (') as separator base on xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html or Indian format seem different. thanks

Comment: Hi cybernate, could you please help me one more?, how to avoid another characters or alphabet except dot or comma supplied? e.g. $11,111.11 or 11,111.11Y (just read the numeric include dot and comma then avoid else? thanks