# Numeric values rounding down unexpectedly

Tags: php, math, rounding, addition, subtraction

I have a loop that calculates a couple revenue values then adds them together, like this:

```
$SalesGrowth = $C2012Sales+$C2011Sales;
```

In some cases, this works, and I get the expected, e.g.: 761.9 + 759.0 = 1520.9

In others, it looks like PHP randomly decides to round incorrectly (??) AND change the units (??) and I get:

8,788.0 + 8,794.3 = 16

What is going on here? I've even tried echoing out the separate sales values separated by a space, and they show up correctly, so the underlying figures aren't wrong.

Comment: It just looks like it doesn't appreciate the comma, doesn't it?

Comment: @fge: not sure if you have a dry sense of humor, but that comment made me laugh :)

Comment: check out money_format on php.net

Comment: Interestingly, while `number_format` converts numbers to localized strings, there doesn't appear to be an inverse, i.e. a locale-aware string parser. Here is [one previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format) on the subject.

Comment: [`Zend_locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html) might help.

Answer (score 9):

Interpreted as a number, `8,788.0` is just `8`, and parsing stops at the comma.

You'll need some locale-aware number parsing if you want to allow gimmicks like thousands-separators.

---

*Update:* If you have the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html), you can do this:

```
require_once('Zend/Locale/Format.php');

$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_GB'); // #1

$v = "8,410.5";
$n = Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($v, array('locale' => $locale,'precision' => 3));

echo 2 * $number;   // prints "16821"
```

Instead of hard-coding the locale, you could try and take it from the environment: `new Zend_Locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))`

Comment: Thanks -- the thing is, the commas are being printed by DataTable.js (a  javascript library for showing sorting tables, etc.) so that's how I pasted them here -- the actual sales figures are just being pulled out of a MySQL database and calculated beforehand...

Comment: Ohhhhhh -- does number_format() insert commas? I think that's what was going on...

Comment: @BenWilson: If you can, use the actual numbers from the database, and not some formatted string representation.

Comment: @BenWilson: It does in some cases, but I think you have to request thousands separators explicitly. But *don't use formatted strings* if you already have the actual numerical data!

Answer (score 3):

Dude the comma issue....

remove all the commas from the numbers before adding them...

```
str_replace(",","",$no1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple... When you ask PHP to use the `+` operator, it will implicitly convert these strings such as `"8,788.0"` to an numeric value.  Since you have a `,` character, it terminates the usefulness of the number, and it results in it being interpreted as `8`.  And so on...

Get rid of the non `[0-9.]` characters and it will work better.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 761.9 is a valid number, while 8,788.0 is not (from PHP's point of view).

So `8,788.0` in number context will evaluate as 8, just like `8,794.3`. And 8+8 = 16.

To fix this problem, process your data to make numbers formatted properly.