# Working with English, Arabic, and Chinese in MySQL

Tags: mysql, localization, character-encoding

**A few questions regarding character sets:**

1. When storing English, Arabic, and Chinese in a MySQL database, is there any **characters set** that supports all of these languages?
2. Will Chinese and Arabic numbers still store in Integer and decimal type fields?
3. Are there any other limitations I am not thinking about?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use UTF to store the text.  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

for numbers, the database stores the actual number, in binary, and not any particular representation of that number.  what you need to do is display the numbers in the client program using the correct locale.  for php see [PHP: Locale aware number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format) (although i suspect that may only do things like choose the correct symbol for the decimal point, and not change from 0-9 for digits).

for more background see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization