# Removing currency symbol from formatCurrency

Tags: php, numberformatter

I'm trying to format revenue totals as grabbed from a db, and using php's NumberFormatter class, with the formatCurrency method.

However, I do not want to print out the actual € / Euro symbol with this. I just want the plain number, with comma's and decimal points.

Example;
1234.56 should be formatted as 1,234.56
The current output is giving €1,234.56.

Code I'm using:

```
$array['total_revenue'] = $this
    ->db
    ->query($sql)
    ->row_array()['SUM( booking_total )'];

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

echo $formatter->formatCurrency($array['total_revenue'], 'EUR') . PHP_EOL;
```

Would anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this up to remove the euro symbol?

Comment: Can't you just change `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` to `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` ?

Comment: why not use number_format ?

Comment: @MuratCemYALIN That won't change the string to use the locales monetary formatting.

Comment: @JonStirling yep, that worked perfectly. Thanks! If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it?

Comment: use money_format then. i guess ! flag will remove the currency symbol

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex is a quick fix for your problem. Try;

```
$actual = $formatter->formatCurrency($array['total_revenue'], 'EUR') . PHP_EOL;
$output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,"."]/', '', $actual );
echo $output;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the regex removes anything not a number, comma or dot but some locales use other symbols (eg Norway uses spaces as group separators) - better to use the `setSymbol` answer!

Answer (score 13):

You should use `setSymbol()` function:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
echo $formatter->formatCurrency($array['total_revenue'], 'EUR') . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: fyi: For the locale de_DE it still has the separator "NO-BREAK SPACE - 0xc2 0xa0" included - and I somehow can't get rid of it.

Comment: Same problem here. I use $result = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $result); to remove it. Better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 13):

I came here because for some reason, `$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');` was being ignored by `$formatter->formatCurrency($array['total_revenue'], 'USD');`

To resolve this issue, I found out a solution here.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setsymbol.php#124153

> this could be obvious to some, but `setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '')` doesn't work for `formatCurrency` - it will simply be ignored...
>
> use `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` and `$fmt->format(123);` to get a currency value with the symbol specified as `CURRENCY_SYMBOL` (or `INTL_CURRENCY_SYMBOL`)

i.e

```php
function currencyFormatter(float $currency, string $locale, int $fractionDigits): string
{
    $fmt = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $fmt->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
    $fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, $fractionDigits);

    return preg_replace(
        '/[[:^ascii:]]/',
        '',
        $fmt->format($currency)
    );
}

echo currencyFormatter(56868993064.7985, 'de_DE', 2);
//Output: 56.868.993.064,80
```

Answer (score 0):

The `formatCurrency()` method is convenient in that it automatically formats the amount according to the rules of the specified currency. For example, when formatting an amount in Euros, the number should show 2 decimal places. But when formatting an amount in Yen, the number should have no decimals as fractions of Yen do not exist (as far as I know). Other currencies may have 3 or even 4 decimals.

If the goal is to keep all functionality of the `formatCurrency()` method except for the removal of the currency symbol (or code), then I'd suggest this snippet:

```
$localeCode = 'en_US';
$currencyCode = 'USD';
$amount = 10000;

$formatter = new \NumberFormatter($localeCode, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatter->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, $currencyCode);
$formatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
$formatter->format($amount);
```

Please note that it is necessary to set the currency code BEFORE clearing the currency symbol. Trying to set the currency after clearing the symbol will not work, as setting the currency will automatically load the related symbol.