# Wrong calculations in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate in PHP. When I try to do that I can see that the result is mostly wrong.

The script I am using is the following:

```
$newrate = 1 / $rate["rate"];
echo '1 /'. $rate["rate"]. ' = '.$newrate;
```

The result I get is the following:

```
1 /1.0867 = 1
1 /117.01 = 0.0085470085470085
1 /1.9558 = 1
1 /27.534 = 0.037037037037037
1 /7.4589 = 0.14285714285714
```

`1 /1.0867` should be `0.92021717125` and not `1`.

I can reproduce this step by adding the following line to my script:

```
$rate["rate"] = 1.0867;
```

When I run the script the result is still `1`. When I change my script like:

```
$newrate = 1 / 1.0867;

echo '1 / 1.0867 = '.$newrate;
```

I get a correct result. The output is then: `0.92021717125`.

Does someone know what is wrong with this script? What is the reason that my script is making incorrect calculations?

**Update 1:**

Here is my full script:

```
<?php
    $XML=simplexml_load_file("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml");

    foreach($XML->Cube->Cube as $rat)
    {

        foreach($rat as $rate)
        {

            $newrate = '1' / $rate["rate"];
            echo '1 /' . $rate["rate"] . ' = ' . $newrate;
            echo '<br /><br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: John, you are doing something else wrong, so maybe it's better if you post the whole code

Comment: There's probably somewhere that you're converting `$rate["rate"]` to an integer.

Comment: I have updated my first post. You can reproduce it with my new code

Comment: I ran your updated code. The first line of the output was `1 /1.0867 = 0.92021717125242` — no errors that I can see. I think you almost certainly have a comma in your code instead of a period, as pointed out by @ThiagoMata. **EDIT:** This might be caused by a locale issue. In some European countries, a comma is used instead of a period as a decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculations are fine, *and correct*

You've not taken into account implicit type casting in PHP. Try this:

```
<?php

print "integer divided by float = " . (1 /1.0867) . "\n"; // returns 0.9202171712524 

print "Integer divided by string = " . ((1/"1.0867") . "\n";  // returns 1
```

You are expecting PHP to *know* what your intention is when you throw a tring into an arithmetic operation - that's not how PHP works.

Just because it is dynamically typed doesn't mean you don't need to be careful with your data types.

```
print (1/(float)$rate['rate'];
```

Comment: This answer is not correct.
```
print "Integer divided by string = " . (1/"1.0867") . "\n";
// Integer divided by string = 0.92021717125242
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your example. I tested exactly what you described and works as expected.

```php
<?php
$rate = [];
$rate["rate"] = "1.0867";
$newrate = 1 / $rate["rate"];
echo '1 / ' . $rate["rate"] . ' = ' . $newrate;
// 1 / 1.0867 = 0.92021717125242
```

You can see it running here
https://repl.it/@thiagodamata/NeighboringPeachpuffArchitect

Probably, you are using "," instead of "." when sending the number.

PHP cast the number only until it hits something unexpected. So "1,0867" is cast to 1. It is a classic problem when dealing with numbers in different formats, considering different languages.

```php
<?php
// simulating the "," error
$rate["rate"] = "1,0867";
$newrate = 1 / $rate["rate"];
echo '1 / ' . $rate["rate"] . ' = ' . $newrate;
// 1 / 1,0867 = 1
```

Take a look in this thread about how to cast the number from different languages masks [PHP: Locale aware number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437371/php-locale-aware-number-format) and take a deeper look into the PHP function number-format https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number_format.php

## Update - After getting the full code example

Looking to your full code becomes more clear the problem. The var that you are getting in the loop it is a SimpleXmlElement, not a string. So, SimpleXmlElement is printed as the "1.0867" but it is not its real value.

To make the SimpleXmlElement cast to float properly, you need to use the cast function.

```php
<?php
    $XML=simplexml_load_file("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml");

    foreach($XML->Cube->Cube as $rat)
    {

        foreach($rat as $rate)
        {
           print(var_dump($rate["rate"]));
            /*
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
              [0]=>
              string(6) "1.0867"
            }
            */

            print("class = [" . get_class($rate["rate"]) . "]\n");
            // class = [SimpleXMLElement]

            print("as string = [" . $rate["rate"] . "]\n");
            // as string = [1.0867]

            print("without cast = [" . (1 * $rate["rate"]) . "]\n");
            // without cast = [1]

            $a = (float)($rate["rate"]);
            print("with cast = [" . ($a) . "]\n");
            // with cast = [1.0867]

            print(serialize($a));
            //d:1.0867;

            $newrate = '1' / $a;
            echo '1 / ' . $a . ' = ' . $newrate . "\n";
            // 1 / 1.0867 = 0.92021717125242
            echo '<br /><br />';
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

You can see this running here:
https://repl.it/@thiagodamata/FuchsiaLightheartedPrintablecharacter

Just printing the value of a var does not always give you the real value of some object. There are other functions like var_export https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php, var_dump https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php and serialize that may help you to see the real value of the vars.

Comment: I have updated my first post. You can reproduce it with my new code

Comment: The real issue was related to the value that you are trying to read is a SimpleXMLElement, not a string. I add more details in answer to make that more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

try cast all values as a float

```
echo 1.0 / (float) $rate['rate'];
```